# Removing newline in file in Python (with certain conditions)

Tags: python, text-files

so I have a utf-8 text file the looks like that:

```
10/02/2016, 19:08 - tel aviv
10/02/2016, 19:09 - best place in the worlds
10/02/2016, 19:09 - let's see
what do you think?
10/02/2016, 19:10 - ‪yay!
I don't mind
10/02/2016, 19:11 - I care
```

and my desired text file output is:

```
10/02/2016, 19:08 - tel aviv
10/02/2016, 19:09 - best place in the worlds
10/02/2016, 19:09 - let's see what do you think?
10/02/2016, 19:10 - ‪yay! I don't mind
10/02/2016, 19:11 - I care
```

Means in any line without a date in the beginning, I would like to `backspace` the line to the line before.

What should I do after I recognize the problematic lines? how I can take them to the line before?

Comment: is the file large or no?

Answer (score 1):

My quick approach

```
text = '''
10/02/2016, 19:08 - tel aviv
10/02/2016, 19:09 - best place in the worlds
10/02/2016, 19:09 - let's see
what do you think?
10/02/2016, 19:10 - ‪yay!
I don't mind
10/02/2016, 19:11 - I care
'''
from re import findall as re_findall
new_text = ''
DATE_PATTERN = '[\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}'

for line in text .split('\n'):
    # if line starts by a date
    if re_findall(DATE_PATTERN, line):
        # add a break and the new line
        new_text += '\n' + line + ' '
    else:
        # if not, we just add the line
        new_text += line

print(new_text)
'''
10/02/2016, 19:08 - tel aviv 
10/02/2016, 19:09 - best place in the worlds 
10/02/2016, 19:09 - let's see what do you think?
10/02/2016, 19:10 - ‪yay! I don't mind
10/02/2016, 19:11 - I care
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Having your text in a file called `input.txt`:

```
10/02/2016, 19:08 - tel aviv
10/02/2016, 19:09 - best place in the worlds
10/02/2016, 19:09 - let's see
what do you think?
10/02/2016, 19:10 - ‪yay!
I don't mind
10/02/2016, 19:11 - I care
```

This code generates an `output.txt` file with the desired format:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as read_file, open("output.txt", "w") as write_file:
    for idx, line in enumerate(read_file.readlines()):
        if line.strip()[0].isdigit() and idx != 0:
            write_file.write("\n")
        write_file.write(line.replace('\n', ' '))
```

Comment: Instead of `line.strip()`, you need `line.replace('\n',' ')`

Comment: Right @rahlf23! Editting it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import re

def reformat_file(fp, fo):
    with open(fp, 'r') as fin, open(fo, 'w') as fout:
        date_reg_exp = re.compile('(\d+[-/]\d+[-/]\d+)')
        for line in fin:
            if date_reg_exp.findall(line):
                try:
                    _next = fin.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    _next = ''
                if date_reg_exp.findall(_next):
                    fout.write(line)
                    fout.write(_next)
                else:
                    fout.write(line.strip('\n') + ' ' + _next)
```

Where `fp` is the filepath of the input file and `fo` is the desired name and location of the output file

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way using date parser.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
with open("yourtext.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in f:
        if is_date(str(line).split(' ', 1)[0])==True:
            #first condition
        else:
            #second condition
```